# How to get the buttons side by side on the same row?

Tags: html, css

I was getting the data from an API and displaying it using HTML.

```css
#dat {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1><u>Weather App</u></h1>
<div id="dat">
  <p id="data"></p>
  <p id="temp"></p>
  <p id="time"></p>

  <button onclick="convertc()">imperial</button>
  <button onclick="convertf()">metric</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that both the buttons are one above another.I want to bring it on the same line.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of the "developer console"? Press F12 and delve into the debugging magic...

Comment: you set a width of `100px` to the parent of the buttons. They can't fit inside 100px. You need to increase that width

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allow enough width for both buttons to fit.

I changed the width to 200px;

```css
#dat{
  position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
button{
 margin-left:20px;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<h1><u>Weather App</u></h1>
  <div id="dat">
    <p id="data">
    </p>
    <p id="temp">
    </p>
    <p id="time">
    </p>

  <button onclick="convertc()">imperial</button>
  <button onclick="convertf()">metric</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the buttons are inside the `#dat` div which is set to be only 100px wide. If you want them to be centered on the same line, add a new div **outside** the `#dat` div with `width: 100%` and `text-align: center`.

```css
#dat {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline;
}

#buttondiv {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1><u>Weather App</u></h1>
<div id="dat">
  <p id="data">
  </p>
  <p id="temp">
  </p>
  <p id="time">
  </p>
</div>
<div id="buttondiv">
  <button onclick="convertc()">imperial</button>
  <button onclick="convertf()">metric</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add some borders to the divs, then you see, that this might collide with the absolutely positioned `#dat` container. Better to keep it nested or change the positioning of both containers to the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach then above, using `floatleft;` and `auto` width.

Created CSS classes as re-useables.

```css
#dat {
  position: absolute;  
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: auto;
}

.pull-left {
  float:left;  
}

.ml-10 {
  margin-left: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<h1><u>Weather App</u></h1>
<div id="dat">
  <p id="data"></p>
  <p id="temp"></p>
  <p id="time"></p>
  
  <button onclick="convertc()" class="pull-left">imperial</button>
  <button onclick="convertf()" class="pull-left ml-10">metric</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your two buttons in different div and apply CSS in each div to adjust width.

```
<div>
<button onclick="convertc()">imperial</button>
</div>
<div>
<button onclick="convertf()">metric</button>
</div>
```

Beside, you can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to keep them inline for every devices.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions would be as follows:

1. Do not use the `<u>` tag for underlining unlinked text. This visual mechanism signifies something clickable. Using it for non-actionable text is bad UX.
2. Use an `<ul>` tag for the data items rather than `<p>` tags. Semantically the information is a list and not paragraphs of textual information.
3. For the `<div>` tags, use 100% width so that your UI is scalable with the visitors viewport. The CSS will continue to center the buttons as the viewport size changes.

See the following code:

```css
#dat {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#dat ul
{
  list-style:none;
  margin:10px 0;
  padding:0;
}

#dat .btns
{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#dat .btns button {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>Weather App</h1>
<div id="dat">
  <ul>
    <li id="data"></li>
    <li id="temp"></li>
    <li id="time"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="btns">
    <button onclick="convertc()">imperial</button>
    <button onclick="convertf()">metric</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.Appreciate it.I have one doubt,why is using a ul better that paragraph?

Comment: The benefit is in writing semantic markup (a topic bigger than I can describe in a comment), but in short Semantic HTML is the use of HTML markup to reinforce the semantics, or meaning, of the information in webpages and web applications rather than merely to define its presentation or look. The information you are displaying is a list of data rather than full paragraphs of textual content making a list tag more appropriate.